# MonoTouch - IOS5 Storyboard - Additional View Controllers

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios5, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I am new to Monotouch and I am not finding the right documentation to do this.

I created a new iPad `Storyboard` Single View application.  I have my inital Navigation Controller, my initial View Controller, and then I added two more View Controllers (Pages?).  I created a button on the first two pages.  I held down control and dragged each button to the next View Controller and setup each Segue as a push.  When I run my application, I can move from page 1 to page 3 and back, no problems.

Now the problem is when I start adding controls and trying to wire them up.  On the initial View Controller, I can hold down Control and drag controls over to the code and after I give it a name, it automatically adds my outlets and actions.

But the new two View Controllers I cannot do this.  I have searched every where and the StoryBoard documentation and examples are difficult to find.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a UIViewController class for each of the new View Controllers in Xcode, if you right click on the folder for where you want to create the class, then click Add New.

You then need to then wire them up to your View Controllers in the storyboard (you will see a drop down which shows the name of the class for the view controller in the properties I think it's the fourth icon from the right, it will be UIViewController).  Once you have done this, you will then be able to wire up the controls on it.

Once you've saved it, it will automatically create the C# classes in MonoDevelop when you switch back to MonoDevelop.  Don't try and do the class in Mono first as it causes you all sorts of issues!

Hope that helps, if you want more information about storyboards, I've found that the objective c stuff is about as good as you can get for now as there isn't too much support for monotouch storyboarcs yet.

Davoc